# Two Methods of computing E[X] but I get 2 different answers instead of the same

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

The 1st method is $\int_{A}^{B}xf(x) dx$ and the 2nd method is $A+\int_{A}^{B} 1-F(X)$ I have the following CDF $$F(X)=\begin{cases} 0\qquad x<2\\ \dfrac{(x-2)^2}{3}+0.3\qquad 2\leq x < 3\\1 \qquad x\geq 3 \end{cases}$$ I worked this out both methods and I got 2 different answers. 
The 1st method I got $$E[X]=\int_{2}^{3}\dfrac{2x(x-2)}{3}+\dfrac{1}{3}$$ since it is the continous part plus the discrete part which yields $\dfrac{8}{9}$ However the other method yields something totally different. Is there a certain condition that needs to be satisfied in order to use the other one that works with the CDF? Because we have $$E[X]=2+\int_2^30.7-\dfrac{(x-2)^2}{3}+\dfrac{1}{3}$$ which obviously does not yield the same answer.

Comment: There may be problems with the equations. Is it really $0.3$? And if the expressions are correct there is also a discrete part at $x=3$.

Comment: Its 0.3 but the discrete part is 1/3 its not part of the integration I just add it to find the expected value

Comment: There is then a discrete weight of $0.3$ at $2$, giving a contribution of $(2)(0.3)$ to the mean, and a discrete weight of $1-\frac{1}{3}-0.3$ at $3$, giving a contribution of $3(1-\frac{1}{3}-0.3)$.

Comment: So does that mean if x is less than 2 than that probability is 0.3

Comment: It doesn't, the description of $F(x)$ (typo there) is explicit. No weight before $2$, discrete weight at $2$ and at $3$, density stuff between $2$ and $3$.

Comment: There shouldn't be a 0.3 than right

Comment: It should have 0 weight

Comment: The function $F(x)$ given **is** a cdf. But maybe you do not intend what you wrote, I do not know. As It is given, its mean can be computed. Since you did not say precisely what your first computed mean was, one cannot say whether it is right. Certainly the contribution of the continuous part is $\frac{8}{9}$.

Comment: This is a question I had to solve. No typo there.

Comment: Fine, what answer did you get using the first method? The typo I was referring to was $F(X)$. Of course it is supposed to be $F(x)$, or $F_X(x)$.

Comment: I gwt 8/9 for the expected value

Comment: That is incorrect. It does not take into account the discrete weights at $2$ and at $3$. The additional terms we need are mentioned in one of my earlier comments.

Comment: I get 3.7 when I take into account both weights is this what you got

Comment: I get $\frac{8}{9}+1.7$.

Comment: Can you post your setup and a quick explanation of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We calculate $E(X)$. Note that as $x$ approaches $2$ from the left, $F(x)$ approaches $0$. But $F(2)=0.3$, so there is a point mass of $0.3$ at $x=2$.

Similarly, as $x$ approaches $3$ from the left, $F(x)$ approaches $\frac{1}{3}+0.3$. But $F(1)=1$, so there is a point mass of $0.7-\frac{1}{3}$ at $x=3$. It follows that
$$E(X)=2(0.3)+3\left(0.7-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\int_2^3 x\frac{2(x-2)}{3}\,dx.$$
Calculate. We get $1.7+\frac{8}{9}$.

**Remark:** Let $U$ be the random variable that has value $2$ with probability $1$. Let $V$ be the random variable which is $3$ with probability $1$. Finally, let $W$ be the random variable which has density function $3\frac{2(x-2)^2}{3}$ between $2$ and $3$, and $0$ elsewhere. (The $3$ in front is to make it a density.) Then
$$X= 0.3U +(0.7-\frac{1}{3})V+\frac{1}{3}W.$$
By the linearity of expectation, we have
$$E(X)=0.3E(U) +(0.7-\frac{1}{3})E(V(+\frac{1}{3}E(W).$$
Calculate. We get the answer already obtained.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you multiply by 2 and 3. I get where the discrete weight comes from

Comment: We are considering all values of x greater than 3 and less than 2

Comment: Recall the notion of mean (moment) for a discrete distribution. If a random variable $Y$ takes value $5$ with probability $p$, $7$ with probability $q$, and $12$ with probability $r$, where $p+q=r=1$, the rv has expectation $5p+7q+12r$.

Comment: But what I'm saying is x could be 100 or it could be -100 What's wrong with those numbers

Comment: It could not. The cumulative distribution function tells us there is no mass to the left of $2$, and no mass to the right of $3$.